Permissiblity of musical instruments on Fridays and other days of Eids
Musical instruments are considered haram as per sahih hadiths like Sahih Bukhari-5590, but other hadiths like Sahih Muslim-892a and Ibn Majah-1898 seems to permit the use of musical instruments on Eids. So is it permissible to play musical instruments on Fridays, because Fridays are considered Eid days?

Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help].

If we solely rely on the Qur'an and the sahih hadiths from the six major hadith collections (Kutub al-Sittah) for Islamic rulings, then all musical instruments, except those that are explicitly prohibited like bells (Sahih Muslim 2114) and kubah (Sunan Abi Dawud 3685, 3696), are permissible on days of Eid. When a hadith seems to permit elements of something that is forbidden, then we look for the reason (or reasons) why those elements were permitted.
In the hadith (Sahih Muslim 892 a), when Abu Bakr rebuked the girls for playing daff on the day of Eid, the prophet replied:

“Abu Bakr, every people have a festival and it is our festival”

There are two possibilities:
1)The prophet permitted the girls to play because the instruments they were playing were daffs, which are different from other instruments and permissible to play on Eids.
2)Daffs are not different from other instruments, but the prophet permitted the girls to play them because it was the day of Eid.
But point 1) seems to be incorrect hence the only possibility is point 2). Reason: If daff were a permitted instrument then Abu Bakr wouldn't have called it an instrument of satan. When Abu Bakr referred to the daff that the girls were playing as an instrument of Satan, the prophet would have replied to Abu Bakr by saying that they were playing daff. However the prophet didn't say anything like that. This means that he agreed with the statement of Abu Bakr regarding the daff (i.e "instrument of satan"). So Daff is also like any other instrument. It has no special status. He permitted it because it was the day of eid. This is clear from his statement- i.e, “Abu Bakr, every people have a festival and it is our festival”. Hence we conclude that all musical instruments, except those that are explicitly prohibited like bells (Sahih Muslim 2114) and kubah (Sunan Abi Dawud 3685, 3696), are permissible on Eid. Since Fridays are Eid days (Sunan Abi Dawud 1073), this conclusion is valid for Fridays as well.
However, this is not how Islamic rulings work. Scholars derive these rulings not only from the Quran and Hadith but also refer to the views of the four Imams. According to all four Imams, every musical instrument is forbidden except for the daff.

Any proof for why point 1) should be incorrect?

@Medi1Saif already explained in the answer

If it was would I have asked?

@Medi1Saif Brother the Reason is given in the answer. If you are unable to find then use "find in page" option in your browser and type "reason", it will show you the keyword in my answer
